# Jquery: how to access only a specified div inside a table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

I am having trouble hiding/showing ONLY 1 div at a time inside a table with Jquery. 
I have a 2 rows in a table: the 1st row contains a link that will toggle a div (.displayMail) inside the second row. There are many instances of these rows, so when I click on the link it should only update the very next div below it, but its updating all divs!!?? Anybody care to help out a noob?

Here is my table,generated with a while loop by php, in which the number of rows change depending on the ttl. number of rows.

```
<table id="inboxTable" class="txt13" width="800px">
<tr><th style="text-decoration:underline">From</th><td width="20px"></td><th style="text-decoration:underline">Subject
    </th><td width="20px"></td>
    <th style="text-decoration:underline">Date</th><td width="20px"></td>
    <th style="text-decoration:underline">Action</th></tr>';

while($info=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $this->requestsMail .='
    <tr>
    <td width="100px"><a href="#" class="showMail" onClick="viewMail()">read</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="7"><div class="displayMail" style="margin:10px 120px 10px 120px" onClick="viewMail()">View Message</div></td></tr>
    ';
}

      $this->requestsMail .='</table>
```

In Jquery, I have this:

```
    function viewMail(){
    $("a.showMail").click(function() {
        $(".displayMail").toggle(); 
        return false;
    });}
```

I can get the link to update ALL divs, but I want to only update the corresponding div.
I tried so many combinations of accessing (".displayMail") by using next(), children(), parents()...basically everything, but still I can't get it where when I click on the corresponding. So many hours trying to get this working :(

Comment: Can I just ask why you are putting a `click()` handler inside a function which you call on the `onClick()` handler of this same element you have the `click()` handler on? That's kind of redundant, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some DOM traversing.

```
function viewMail(){
    $("a.showMail").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.displayMail').toggle();
        return false;
    });
}
```

By just selecting `.displayMail` jQuery will correctly query **all** those divs. By invoking [`.closest('tr')`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) we traverse the DOM up until the very first instance of `<tr>`. From there we go to the next `<tr>` invoking [`.next()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and finally search that node with [`.find()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for the correct instance of `.displayMail`.

**update**

I just realized your calling convention. By calling `viewMail` in the `onclick` handler, you would bind another click handler each time. So should just call:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.showMail").click(function() {
         $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.displayMail').toggle();
         return false;
   });
});
```

This will bind the click-event handler once. Remove the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: You are awsome jAndy!! I should have posted a couple of hours ago, haha. Thanks a bunch! Nice explanations also. So next() can only be applied as a reference to the previous element specified (closest(tr)) right?

Comment: @Anriëtte: nothing at all. It looked like a downvote thing, nevermind. Anyway you are correct, I didn't realize how the OP is calling this method.

Comment: @jAndy: If you look closely, you will see that he's calling `viewMail()` from an `onClick` handler on the `<div>` as well: `<div class="displayMail" style="margin:10px 120px 10px 120px" onClick="viewMail()">`, hence my answer below.

Comment: You all are awesome. Thanks for all the help. I took your advice and removed the onClick attributes. Working like a charm now! : )

Answer (score 0):

```
function viewMail(){
    $("a.showMail").click(function() {
        $(this).parent('tr').next().find(".displayMail").toggle(); 
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: `.parent()` only travels a single level, that would be the `<td>` node.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `viewMail()` function and change the jQuery to this:

```
$("a.showMail").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.displayMail').toggle();
    return false;
});

$("div.displayMail").click(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    return false;
});
```